# How to set cornerRadius of a cell's contentView after setting layoutMargins for it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout, cornerradius

I can't setup the corner radius of a custom UITableViewCell after setting layoutMargins to the cell's contentView:

```
self.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(margin, margin, margin, margin)
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0 // Will not show, because of the layoutMargins.
```

Any solution for that will be appreciated.

**Edit**

Currently have a table view with layoutMargins set to all cells:
[image]

And I want to achieve a table view with layoutMargins and cornerRadiuses to all cells:
[image]

Comment: Some screenshots of what you currently have and what you trying to achieve would help

Comment: Where are you adding these lines of code?

Comment: - Edited with screenshots.
- These lines of code are in a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Did you try setting `clipsToBounds` property to `YES` on your `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`?

Comment: @AleksanderGrzyb Yes, I did, But still not working.

Comment: This gray color is the `backgroundColor` of `contentView` or some subview in `contentView`?

Comment: The gray behind is just from the screenshots i took from the 'Preview'.

Comment: Try to set `masksToBounds` to `YES`.

Comment: Tried this one too, still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is possible I would suggest you not to do it this way. Try avoiding setting such values to internal views as they may be tempered by the system owning the view (the cell itself).

What you should do is create another view and put it on the content view (is best done in storyboard). Then manipulate that view. You will have to set the content view background to clear color and also as mentioned in comments do not forget to set clip subviews on your new view.

Also you may set the corner radius in storyboard on any view by adding a "User Defined Runtime Attribute" as Key path : layer.cornerRadius; Type : Number; Value : 4.

Any of these will work programmatically as well.

Answer (score -2):

Hi i have batter solution if you are looking for corner radius for content view.
you can use  for the content view as next child and give corner to fram.
ex-

```
                </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
```